# Regular expression in mySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a mysql table that has 2 columns - Column 1 contains a string value, and Column 2 contains the number of times that string value occurred.

I'm trying to find the string abc.X.def, where the beginning of the string is "abc.", followed by one or more characters, then the string ".def". There could be more characters following ".def".

How can I find such strings, then add the occurrence of such strings and display the results?

For example, if I have

```
abc.111.def23   1
abc.111.def     2
abc.22.def444   1
abc.111.def     1
```

Then I will get

```
abc.111.def23   1
abc.111.def     3
abc.22.def444   1
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use `LIKE` and `SUM`:

```
SELECT StringValue, SUM(InstanceSubCount) AS InstanceCount
FROM ValueInstanceSubcounts
WHERE StringValue LIKE 'abc.%.def%'
GROUP BY StringValue
```

Note the `GROUP BY` clause, since your table doesn't seem to have a primary or unique key on StringValue. Also, note the second `%` after 'def', since your string values don't end with '.def' but can actually have some digits after that, it would seem. For that, if your free characters are always decimal digits (`[0-9]`), you might try something like one of these `WHERE` clauses in stead:

```
WHERE StringValue REGEXP '^abc\.\d+\.def\d*$'
WHERE StringValue REGEXP '^abc\.[0-9]+\.def[0-9]*$'
```

They're equivalent, and *require* some digits between the dots/periods (that's what the plus does), and *allow* digits after the 'def' (that's what the asterisk does). The periods themselves need to be escaped with backslash, since otherwise they represent any character. The `^` and `$` tell `REGEXP` to match the complete string, from beginning to end. Lastly, `\d` is shorthand for decimal digits, which can also be represented by the character range `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the 'LIKE' clause, see [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html).

In that clause you can use `%` to match any amount of characters. Resulting in:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE value LIKE 'abc.%.def%'
```

Comment: This would also allow `value = 'abc.def'` since you declare only one `.`

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the connection to regexp here really based on what you have and what you want. This looks more like a `GROUP BY` and `SUM()` case:

```
SELECT str_example, SUM(number)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY str_example
```

`str_example` would be the abc ... def
`number` would be the number which increased in the example

If you want the regexp it's:

```
WHERE str_example REGEXP '^abc\.\+?\.def.*$'
```